# HandshakeFailure in JDK 1.6

Tags: java

I have implemented the HTTPS on my application and it is working fine with the JDK 7 and JDK 8 but while i am testing my client with the JDK 6 i am getting the below error. javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure I have tried with the multiple protocol but didn't got the response 
I have refered the below link for create the certificate https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gjrgy/

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure`

Comment: Could just be that Java 6 does not support newer versions of HTTPS that are now being required by many services. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49040583/can-java-jdk-1-6-0-39-support-tlsv1-2?rq=1  You will need to upgrade Java.

Comment: Check that the certificate authority that registered the cert is in the trusted certificates.  I know letsencrypt for example was only added in later updates so perhaps not in JDK 6

Comment: Java6 doesn't support natively `TLS1.1` nor `TLS1.2`, so that might be the source of the problem. (upgrade 111 think it implements 1.1, but not sure..)

Comment: Thanks Thilo, I have tried with the old protocol as well like sslv3 which i have enabled and tried but didn't work.

Comment: I am getting the below error. 

[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Comment: Hi McGin, I have checked the C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\security\cacerts file and recent entry is present on the file.